# Is it possible to make own shortcuts in r?

Tags: r

Is it possible to make own keyboard shortcuts to the menubar in R Studio?

I made this question before R Studio made it easy accessible at Tools>Modify Keyboard Shortcuts...

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "shortcut", but I write functions all the time, eg. `mySquareFunc <- function(x) { x*x }`

Comment: Do you mean a keyboard shortcut? Like CTRL+Z?

Comment: Made the question more precise

Comment: You can use `winMenuAdd` and related functions to create a menu item that you can access with Alt and then a sequence of letters.

Comment: @James Can you elaborate that?

Comment: It's not clear what you need shortcuts for. However, I'd imagine that you'd better look for keyboard shortcuts in the IDE/editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, that has some caveats, but may be of use.

You can add an new menu with `winMenuAdd`:

```
winMenuAdd("Shortcuts")
```

Then add an item:

```
winMenuAddItem("Shortcuts","Garbage Collect","gc()")
```

Now activate using <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd>:

```
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 232838 12.5     467875   25   350000 18.7
Vcells 346933  2.7     786432    6   786431  6.0
```

Points to note:

- This is only available on Windows, and only guaranteed using the default GUI.
- The letters to access the menus and items are determined by Windows to avoid clashes, so shortcut keys will depend upon existing menus and items.
- The menus will only remain for the current session. If you want it permanently add to your .Rprofile file. Remember that `utils` is not loaded at this point so you have prepend commands with its namespace to use them, eg `utils::winMenuAdd`.

Comment: FYI this does not work in RStudio: winMenuAdd("Shortcuts")
> winMenuAdd("Shortcuts")
Error in winMenuAdd : function not supported in RStudio